# How to get values from other nodes in XSLT body?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<record>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <key>FIRSTKEY</key>
    <value>FIRSTVALUE</value>
</record>
<record>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <key>SECONDKEY</key>
    <value>SECONDVALUE</key>
</record>
```

So each record has the same TITLE.

What I would like to do with XSLT is generate a header based on the information from the first (or any element as they all have the same header info), but within the same document, I want to loop over all the nodes, kind of like so:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <doc>
        <!-- xsl:select first node -->
        <header><title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title></header>
        <!-- /xsl:select -->
        <!-- xsl:for-each loop over all nodes, including the one we selected for the header -->
            <key><xsl:value-of select="key"/></key>
            <value><xsl:value-of select="value"/></value>
        <!-- /xsl:for-each -->
        </doc>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- xsl:select first node -->
    <header><title><xsl:value-of select="record[1]/title"/></title></header>
    <!-- /xsl:select -->
    <!-- xsl:for-each loop over all nodes, including the one we selected for the header -->
     <xsl:for-each select="record">
        <key><xsl:value-of select="key"/></key>
        <value><xsl:value-of select="value"/></value>
     </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- /xsl:for-each -->
</xsl:template>
```

you should get the result you want.

I would however suggest to use a templates based approach with two modes

```
    <xsl:template match="/root">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="record[1]" mode="head"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="record"/>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="record" mode="head">
  <header><xsl:copy-of select="title"/></header>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
  <xsl:copy-of select="key |  value"/>
</xsl:template>
```